# Redeclared 'bot' defined above without usage

Tags: python, discord, pycharm, discord.py

The "bot" variable at the bottom is highlighted and says "Redeclared 'bot' defined above without usage". This is essentially all of my code up until that point. Please help!

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import bot
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord.utils import get
from discord_slash import cog_ext, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import random


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
```

Comment: You defined `bot` first with `from discord.ext import bot`. Now you're reassigning that, so you can no longer use the variable from `discord.ext`.

Comment: `from discord.ext import commands` not bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code imports a module named `bot`:

```
from discord.ext import bot
```

And then this line redefines the name `bot`, replacing the imported module name:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
```